# Vaadin22 get notified when a user clears a textfield

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin22

In Vaadin 22 it's possible to add a clear button to a textfield by calling the following method:

```java
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setClearButtonVisible(true);
```

I wonder if it's possible to get notified when someone clicks the clear button.

I tried to attach a click listener to it by plain javascript. But that is not that simple because the clear button is in the shadow dom.

Comment: Other than the value change event?  So an explicit click (or ESC or whatever) of the user?

Comment: Yes, i wan't to get notified when the button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have this information on the Java side.
As a workaround you can add your own clear button as a suffix component:

```
textfield.setSuffixComponent(myClearButton);
```

And use the clickListener on the button. You will also need to manually display/hide it based on the state of the textfield.

Comment: Sadly, this is the only option i found... Thank you anyways.